# How to reference Microsoft.Solver.Foundation in vs12?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solver, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to add Solver Foundation to a project I'm working on in Visual Studio 2012, but I can't find it in the list.

I opened one of the example projects, and the reference is Microsoft.Solver.Foundation however I tried searching Microsoft.S on all of the available lists, in my project, and it didn't come up.

How do I get Solver Foundation into my project?

Comment: Which operating system are you running? Do you have VS 2010 installed alongside? And which MSF version and edition are you running? When I chose _Open With..._ VS 2012 the MSF project opened and executed without problems on Windows 8.

Comment: MSF latest version. The project works fine, i just can't import it into my own project.

Comment: Targeting .Net 4.5 instead of .Net 4 is what kept me from seeing the dll in the reference list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just installed **VS 2012** on my computer. I also have **VS 2010** installed. I've re-installed Solver Foundation, but still no such project type in VS 2012 (unlike VS 2010). I would also like to know how to add this project type to the templates in VS 2012.

However, this might help you: it is enough to add the reference in your project to the `Microsoft.Solver.Foundation.dll`. The location might be:

> C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\
>   .NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.Solver.Foundation.dll

if your Framework version was 4.0 before installing VS 2012.

Answer (score 8):

The *Microsoft.Solver.Foundation* assembly is primarily targeted at .NET 4 and is thus included in the .NET 4 reference assemblies, as is also indicated by *MSt:s* answer.

This means that if you create a project that targets .NET 4.0, the *Microsoft.Solver.Foundation* assembly *will* show up in the *Assemblies / Framework* list when you are adding a new reference in Visual Studio 2012.

On the other hand, the *MSF* assembly will *not* show up if your project is targeting .NET 4.5. If you are targeting .NET 4.5, you will instead need to browse to the assembly manually, typically to the path that *MSt* has pointed out already, i.e. *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0*.